# In timescale db, while querying compressed chunks, segment by indexes are not getting used. How to make sure that indexes are used while querying?

Tags: indexing, timescaledb

Below is my table schema:-

```
CREATE TABLE public.table1
(
   machinecode character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
   groupname character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
   sensor character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
   "time" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
   value1 integer,
   value2 real,   
   PRIMARY KEY (machinecode, groupname,sensor, "time")
)

CREATE INDEX ON table1 (machinecode,groupname,sensor, time DESC);

SELECT create_hypertable('table1', 'time');
SELECT set_chunk_time_interval('table1', INTERVAL '24 hours');

ALTER TABLE table1 SET (
  timescaledb.compress,
  timescaledb.compress_segmentby = 'machinecode,groupname,sensor'
);

SELECT add_compression_policy('table1', INTERVAL '7 days');
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yosl6.png)

But as can be seen from image 1, in explain no index scan is used on machinecode

```
select * from _timescaledb_catalog.hypertable
where id =
(SELECT compressed_hypertable_id FROM _timescaledb_catalog.hypertable
 WHERE table_name='table1');
```

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv09g.png)
From image 2 it can be seen that compressed_hypertable_18 is formed and indexes on same is

```
CREATE INDEX _compressed_hypertable_18_machinecode__ts_meta_sequence_num_idx ON _timescaledb_internal._compressed_hypertable_18 USING btree (machinecode, _ts_meta_sequence_num)
CREATE INDEX _compressed_hypertable_18_groupname__ts_meta_sequence_num_idx ON _timescaledb_internal._compressed_hypertable_18 USING btree (groupname, _ts_meta_sequence_num)
CREATE INDEX _compressed_hypertable_18_sensor__ts_meta_sequence_num_idx ON _timescaledb_internal._compressed_hypertable_18 USING btree (sensor, _ts_meta_sequence_num)
```

But still in explain, query is not using index.

How can i make sure that indexes are used while querying.

Comment: Can you post your reference queries into the question? Putting essential information under the links and inside images complecates answering the question.

Comment: (and entire query plan in text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query plan shows that the issue is casting the column to `TEXT`. [This answer](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/2722#issuecomment-770392688) in GH suggest to use `TEXT` for the segmentby columns. In your case you use type `VARYING`, which introduces the need for casting. And since casting is used on the column, the index cannot be used.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the issue, the column needs to be TEXT type.

Comment: @PriyankaSaxena Great to hear that it helped! Welcome to accept the answer, so hopefully it will help other developers, who might run into the same issue.